# How can I hide zero rows in every worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, for-loop, foreach, show-hide, vba

I want to hide rows that have a zero values in columns B & C. My code works but only on the active worksheet. I want it to loop through all worksheets in the workbook. Any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim M As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim ws As worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
LastRow = ws.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
For M = LastRow To 7 Step -1
If Range("B" & M).Value = 0 And Range("C" & M).Value = 0 Then
Range("B" & M).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next M
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: `1.`What's the purpose of hiding zero-valued rows in two columns across an entire workbook? `2.` How many sheets do you have in the workbook? `3.` What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I started this comment, then realized I had misread what you were trying to do. bonCodigo has asked good questions.

Answer (score 0):

activate the sheet.  The issue is that Range is working off the current active sheet.   If you use ws. infromt of range or activate the worksheet such as below.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

add

```
ws.Activate
```

Comment: It's generally bad practive to use the `.Activate` method. there are much faster ways of doing a task involving `.Activate`.

Comment: @Brad and as always its up to the dev.  Hence why I also stated he could add the ws workbook object to reference the range.

Comment: Maybe, but `.Select` and `.Activate` pretty much guarantee you will have a substantially slower program than equivalent methods that do not actively change the cursor position. Even with `Application.Screenupdating` turned off. You're right it's up to the dev but really...why?

Comment: and again it is the choice of the dev which they want to use and.....why because they are coding it not you.  All you can do is give them the information and let them decide what is best for their project.

Comment: Adding ws to the range worked perfectly and program runs quickly. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found this about the subject, I hope it helps: [ExtendOffice](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/546-excel-hide-rows-with-zero-value.html)

```
Sub Hide_rows()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row '
Set Rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow) '
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Rng
If cell.Value = "0" Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is going to *kill* the workbook....going through each cell in the entire workbook....long journey...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Range as a member of the worksheet like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim M As Long, LastRow As Long
   Dim ws As worksheet

   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       LastRow = ws.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
       For M = LastRow To 7 Step -1
           ' Notice how 'ws' has been added before range
           If ws.Range("B" & M).Value = 0 And ws.Range("C" & M).Value = 0 Then
               ws.Range("B" & M).EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End If
       Next M
   Next ws
 End Sub
```